# Classification theory, forking, type: naming of a set of variables

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

In the snippet below which is taken from the Shelah's book Classification Theory,
what does $U$ in $$\bar{x}_U$$
stand for; why was it named so ?
What type of object is $U$ ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He explains the notation literally a few lines above that at the start of the section. The $U$ here is just an index set. I don't know why he chooses that name.

So what it means is that $\bar{x}_U$ is just a tuple of variables, and for each $k$ we have a subtuple, denoted by $\bar{x}^k$.

Comment: From where your $k$ ranges ? How is this $k$ connected to $U$ ?

Comment: As in your screenshot: an integer $0 \leq k < n$. The point is that the type $p$ forks over $A$ if it implies the distinction of finitely many dividing (over $A$) formulas, each with free variables among the free variables in $p$. The $k$ is just used to index these finitely many formulas.

Comment: What do you mean by **the distinction** ? Everything else is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @user122424  Oops, that was an autocorrect from my phone. Should have been "disjunction".